# What happens to the access token in the multiple auth of Laravel passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Configure the auth.php config file as below:

```
    'guards'    => [
        'web'   => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'api'   => [
            'driver'   => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin-api'   => [
            'driver'   => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users'  => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
    ],
```

I successfully generate access_token for both user and admin.

However, if I get the user's access_token to access the api admin route (`'middleware' => 'auth:admin-api'`), it succeeds.
The information received by request()->user() is the admin account with the same id as the user.
Same thing happens when I use admin token for user access and api.

**Note:**

This scenario only happens when admin and user have the same ID value.

What is going on, or did I do something wrong?
I guess the scenario that happened was as follows:

**Step 1:** user's access_token passes `'middleware' => 'auth:admin-api'`.

**Step 2:** The oauth_access_tokens.user_id value is returned

**Step 3:** From user_id will return the corresponding admin.

So it happens only when user.id and admin.id are same.

Help me clarify this issue. Thanks

If i want to prevent this, what should I do?
Obviously users shouldn't access the admin account-only api

Comment: Do you have admins stored in the same database as regular users ? You shouldn't use multiple guards to implement access control. Middlewares are way to go. You can create admin middleware and apply it on certain routes, controllers or route groups. I sometimes have route file admin.php which corresponds to everything that has prefix '/admin' and then apply 'admin' middleware on that inside RouteServiceProvider.php .

Comment: use a scope when you generate the token. then apply the scope to middleware.

Comment: @NipunTharuksha Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: Any helpful information, thanks

Comment: @AHuy please refer the document https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#defining-scopes

Comment: @NipunTharuksha Thanks so much. I'll check it